# Last line in label for cell wont appear with auto layout and dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, label

I am having some serious trouble getting my multiline label to show all of its lines. Often, the last line of the label simply does not appear, but it is apparent that the dynamically calculated cell height has taken in to account that it should have appeared, leaving around the appropriate amount of white space left over in my cell.

The affected label can display 1-7 lines depending on the data. I have played around with many various constraints to try and get it to display but regardless of what is on the last line, it just won't display.

The weird thing is, sometimes it will display when I segue in to the VC, but then when I use the segmented controller inside the VC to display different data and then go back again, the last line will again not display. The opposite happens frequently too (last line of label cutting off when I segue in to the VC, but then using the segmented controller inside the VC to change the displayed data and then go back, it will then display fine).

Things I have ensured: The label is set to word wrap, has line count of 0, has a height greater than or equal to the height of one of it's lines, its resistance and vertical content hugging is set to the highest of anything in the cell, and the width is set appropriately.

The below code is how I determine how many lines the label will have:

```
let descString = NSMutableAttributedString()

let bountyStart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Bounty: ", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)])
let bountyDesc = NSMutableAttributedString(string: bounty.description)
descString.appendAttributedString(bountyStart)
descString.appendAttributedString(bountyDesc)

let bLine = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\n", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(2)])
descString.appendAttributedString(bLine)

if !(bounty.turtles == 0.0){
    let turtleStart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your turtle count: ")
    let turtleAmount = NSMutableAttributedString(string: bounty.turtleCount.description)
    descString.appendAttributedString(turtleStart)
    descString.appendAttributedString(turtleAmount)
}
descriptionLabel.attributedText = descString
```

In the screen shot below, you can see that the height of the cell is being calculated appropriately but for some reason, the last line of the label just refuses to show. It should appear after the "is for noobs" line. I've manipulated the white space to appear after the line instead of elsewhere by setting the problem labels bottom to constraint to be greater than or equal, and all other top to bottom constraints as equal to.

[image]

Constraints of the problem label:

[image]

I've been stumped for quite a while on this one, and I'm starting to think it's not the constraints I've set but something much deeper. All though I would love to be proven wrong.

Here is my VC code.

```
    import UIKit

class TrendingVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var menubtn:UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var trendingTableView:UITableView!  

    var trendingToggle:Int = 0
    let nwt = NWTrending()
    let appUserId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("UserId") ?? "1" //@TODO: remove ?? 1
    var bountyArr: [Bounty] = []
    var compArr: [Completion] = []
    var peopleArr: [Person] = []

    var userId: String = "0"
    var username: String = ""

    let bountyCellIdentifier = "BountyCellNew"
    let personCellIdentifier = "PersonCell"
    let completedCellIdentifier = "TrendingCompletedImageCell"



    @IBAction func toggleTrending(sender:UISegmentedControl){
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            //loads the bounties on segmented control tab
            trendingToggle=0
            nwt.getTrendingBounties(appUserId, position: 0){(bountyArr, err) in //@TODO: change pos
                self.bountyArr = bountyArr as [Bounty]
                self.reloadTableViewContent()
            }
        case 1:
            trendingToggle=1
            nwt.getTrendingCompletions(appUserId, position: 0){(compArr, err) in
                self.compArr = compArr as [Completion]
                self.reloadTableViewContent()
            }
        case 2:
            trendingToggle=2
            nwt.getTrendingPeople(appUserId, position: 0){(peopleArr, err) in
                self.peopleArr = peopleArr as [Person]
                self.reloadTableViewContent()
            }
        default:
            break
        }

        //reloadTableViewContent()
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trendingTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300.0
    trendingTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


    /******* Kyle Inserted *******/
    //for followers and following back button text, you set it here for when you segue into that section
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    /******* END Kyle Inserted *******/

    trendingTableView.allowsSelection = false;
    trendingTableView.delegate = self
    trendingTableView.dataSource = self

    //sidebar code
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menubtn.target = self.revealViewController()
        menubtn.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    //loads the bounty on segue
    nwt.getTrendingBounties(appUserId, position: 0){(bountyArr, err) in
        self.bountyArr = bountyArr as [Bounty]
        self.reloadTableViewContent()
    }
}


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //deselectAllRows()

    }


    func deselectAllRows() {
        if let selectedRows = trendingTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath] {
            for indexPath in selectedRows {
                trendingTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }

    func reloadTableViewContent() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.trendingTableView.reloadData()
            println("reloading table view content")
            self.trendingTableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), animated: false)
        })
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(trendingTableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if trendingToggle == 0{
        return bountyArr.count
        }
        else if trendingToggle == 1{
            return compArr.count
        }
        else {
            return peopleArr.count
        }
    }


    func tableView(trendingTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if trendingToggle == 0{
            return bountyCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        }
        else if trendingToggle == 1{
            return completedCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        }
        else{
        return personCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        }
    }

    //calls method to set and display each trending bounty cell
    func bountyCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> BountyCellNew {
        let cell = trendingTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(bountyCellIdentifier) as! BountyCellNew
        var bounty = bountyArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.setBountyCellTrending(bounty)
        return cell
    }

    func completedCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CompletedCell{
        let cell = trendingTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(completedCellIdentifier) as! CompletedCell
        var comp = compArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.setTrendingCompletedCell(comp)
        return cell
    }


    func personCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> PersonCell{
        let cell = trendingTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(personCellIdentifier) as! PersonCell
        var peop = peopleArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.setTrendingPeopleCell(peop)
        return cell
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try to print in console `descString` at the end of code. And verify what it contains when it works fine and when it bug.

Comment: @Mindsers I have, that's not the problem. It's a problem with my constraints and auto layout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I updated xcode and now this doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment due to rep low.
This seems like a IB thing, very likely constraints. 
Make sure that any component's top constraint placed under this multiline `UILabel` is set to the bottom of said `UILabel`.

For example, in this project of mine, both the TitleView and TimeAndDetailsView contain `UILabels` that span multiplelines. In order to allow autolayout to properly space things all constraints need to be in order, also notice how the top constraint of TimeAndDetails is the bottom of TitleView
[image]

Edit note:
Before you `tableView.reloadData()` type the following 2 lines, or if uncertain, put it inside `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60 //Type your cell estimated height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimensionhere
```

Comment: The label underneaths top space to the problem label is set to equal a distance of 1

Comment: its fine if it is equal to 1 as long as that is the spacing you want between the labels. Make sure that anything else under the label right under the "problem label" also has a top constraint to the component right above it. For multi lines `UILabel`s is better if everything (constraint wise) follows the hierarchical order layed out in storyboards.

Comment: What do you mean by the hierarchical order laid out in storyboards? I would post a few pictures of my constraints + what the cell should look like vs what's happening but I don't have the 10 reputation to do so.

Comment: I meant, using my project as reference. The uiimageview is irrelevant since it comes before any of the uilabels, so I only gave it a top and left to its superview and a height&width constraint, however, since the titleview is the first element in the view that contain a uilabel that can span multiple lines, then anything below it should have top constraints to the element right above it. The TitleView bottom constraint is set to the top of TimeAndDetailsView, the bottom constraint of TimeAndDetailsView is set to the top locationview.

Comment: and the locationview bottom constraint being the last element in the view has as bottom constraint the bottom layout guide

Comment: wait, did you say this is a cell? you need to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension. Adding note to answer, take a look.

Comment: yes it's a cell. I am using that method in my overridden viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Not sure whats happening from looking at the picture with the black rectangles. Sadly going to bed now. If you already print `descString` and it does have all the text, then you are probably still looking at constraint problems. I know you probably have gone through all of them already many times :-(

Comment: You said you had the height constraint set to >= Int. Where is it?, also, as far as I know, only the height needs the greater than sign, the trailing and top can be set to just equal

Comment: I am very silly, I put the constraints of the wrong label in my question. I have updated it now to the right ones

Comment: Yeah I know, but if I don't put the bottom space to greater than or equal, the white space just displays somewhere else, either at the bottom of the cell or between other labels.

Comment: then you need to remove the >= from all the other elements under the "problem label". Say, you have bottom space to bounty type set to 1, you always want that spacing to be 1 regardless of the size of the 'problem label' so it needs to be = 1 not >= 1. All elements under the label need to have = Int constraints for top/bottom/leading/trailing. Only the height constraint of the multiline label should have >= Int, that way everything under it will move accordingly since they are strictly = Int

Comment: That's what I had originally, I only used the >=1 to control where the white space was going to be. This is how it looks when all top/bottom constraints are equal to 1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sXnjr.png The bottom line still doesn't display, it's just the whitespace is moved else where

Answer (score 0):

Went to sleep last night, ok so I decided to add your code to my details label from the storyboards picture I had posted before, and it seems to have displayed just fine. I have a few questions and pointers below.

[image]

```
let descString = NSMutableAttributedString()
let bountyStart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Bounty: ", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)])
let bountyDesc = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "this would be 'bounty.description and is set to size 40", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(40)])
descString.appendAttributedString(bountyStart)
descString.appendAttributedString(bountyDesc)
let bLine = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\n", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)])
descString.appendAttributedString(bLine)
let turtleStart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your turtle count: ")
let turtleAmount = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "random number 1234 goes here")
descString.appendAttributedString(turtleStart)
descString.appendAttributedString(turtleAmount)
detailsLabel.attributedText = descString
```

Sadly, this is in a scrollview and not in a cell, so there is the first difference. My first question; is your `descriptionLabel.attributedText` supposed to display different fontscolors or fonttypes/sizes?, if not then I would say to just use `descriptionLabel.text` instead of `descriptionLabel.attributedText`. 
Now the fact that there is white space but nothing showing us makes me wonder if `bounty.turtleCount.description` was previously set to color white somewhere else, or you are simply seeing the newlines you added `\n\n` and nothing is there because `if !(bounty.turtles == 0.0)` doesnt execute. Are you sure the that if statement is executed? place a breakpoint and follow along to make sure the values are appended to `descString` 
If this is all correct, then my guess would still be on constraints.
Could you elaborate on, quote from you; "sometimes it will display when I segue in to the VC, but then when I use the segmented controller inside the VC to display different data and then go back again, the last line will again not display." what are you doing different in the seg control when loading the values and reloading the tableview that makes it not display, and under what conditions does it work properly when you segue.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for helping. Yeah, I am displaying different font types colours and sizes. Nope, it's not set to white and yeah, I've double checked a few times. It definitely runs and definitely attaches to the string. You can tell the cell is making room for it, it just doesn't appear. It seems to be random, I have copied the code from another VC and in some VCs it will display and others it won't and sometimes it will display when using a segmented controller and sometimes it won't

Comment: Good luck trying to debug. This is one of the best posts out there on selfsizing cells, maybe there might be a detail listed there that could fix your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights?rq=1

Comment: Alrighty, well, went over the code, maybe I missed something (first time I read your post didnt realize you were talking about cells, LOL), if not, everything looks good to me. Only suggestions not regarding your problem are, no need for all the `self.` in `viewDidLoad`, you only need the `self` in closure blocks, also no need to call  `numberOfSectionsInTableView` if you are not adding more sections, because the default is already 1. Out of curiosity, are all 3 cells 300px height?. Did you go through the link I posted to see if you find anything you could be missing for the self-sizing cells?

Comment: One cell can vary from around 160-240, one cell is always 117 and the other cell can vary from 680-740 (roughly). I did go through it and the things that stuck out (placement of estimatedRowHeight) I changed but they didn't appear to affect anything